# Browser not refresh components in Vue.js PWA

Tags: vue.js, npm, sublimetext3, progressive-web-apps

I have a Vue.js PWA and I am trying to make changes with Sublime Text.

I run it with "npm run dev", but when I change something not refresh in the browser, I have to run the command again.

When I run "npm run build" and "npm run start" I have a problem with my manifest.json:

**start_url does not respond with a 200 when offlineTimed out waiting for fetched start_url.**

But I do not know if two problems are related.

My manifest.json:

```
 {
  "name": "Hegeo Geolocation",
  "short_name": "Hegeo",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#118fe4",
  "icons": [
   {
  "src": "/static/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
  "sizes": "192x192",
  "type": "image/png"
   },
   {
  "src": "/static/img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
  "sizes": "512x512",
  "type": "image/png"
   }
  ]
 }
```

Can be the problem from Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Try to delete `node_modules` then reinstall `npm i`

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed.

Comment: Where do you have your manifest and service worker file? Are they at root level or in some (sub)folder?

Comment: They are in root level. I understood that "npm run dev" not work. When I have a PWA i have to do "npm run build" before. However, in visual studio code "npm run dev" work correctly.